# How to modify the Express route to login the user after it is created in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, express

I have the route below. It works if I manually add Documents in MongoDB. However, I'd like to handle the case when the user is not found, is created, and then is logged in automatically.

What would be the best way to modify this route?

```
router.post("/loginViaFacebook", (req, res) => {
  const userEmail = req.body.email;
  const errors = {};

  User.findOne({ email: userEmail }).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      new User({
        facebookId: req.body.facebookId,
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        pictureUrl: req.body.picture
      }).save();
    } else {
      const payload = {
        facebookId: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        pictureUrl: user.picture
      };

      jwt.sign(payload, secretOrKey, { expiresIn: 3600 }, (err, token) => {
        res.json({ success: true, token: "Bearer " + token });
      });

      console.log("success!");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you save the new User object to the database, you can get the id from the returned result.  I don't know mongo too well, so you'll have to look in the result that comes back from `.save()` and fetch the id out of there.  Here's the general structure:

```
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const jwt.signPromise = promisify(jwt.sign);

/**
 * @route POST api/auth/loginViaFacebook
 * @desc Login User via Facebook/
 * @access public
 */
router.post("/loginViaFacebook", async (req, res) => {
    const userEmail = req.body.email;
    const errors = {};

    try {
        let user = await User.findOne({
            email: userEmail
        });
        if (!user) {
            user = new User({
                facebookId: req.body.facebookId,
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email,
                pictureUrl: req.body.picture
            });
            user = await user.save();
        }
        const payload = {
            facebookId: user.facebookId,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            pictureUrl: user.picture
        };

        let token = await jwt.signPromise(payload, secretOrKey, {expiresIn: 3600});
        res.json({success: true, token: "Bearer " + token});

    } catch (e) {
        // send some sort of error response here
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

If you want to stick with your original structure without using `await`, you can just move the duplicated code into a common function.

```
/**
 * @route POST api/auth/loginViaFacebook
 * @desc Login User via Facebook/
 * @access public
 */
router.post("/loginViaFacebook", (req, res) => {
  const userEmail = req.body.email;
  const facebookId = req.body.facebookId;

  function finish(user) {
    const payload = {
      facebookId: user.facebookId,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      pictureUrl: user.picture
    };

    jwt.sign(payload, secretOrKey, { expiresIn: 3600 }, (err, token) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.sendStatus(500);
          return;
      }
      res.json({ success: true, token: "Bearer " + token });
    });
    return;
  }

  // Find user by email. ( Down below { email } in ES6 is same as { email: email }
  User.findOne({ email: userEmail }).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      new User({
        facebookId: facebookId,
        name: req.body.name,
        email: userEmail,
        pictureUrl: req.body.picture
      }).save(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({ errors: err });
            return;
        }
        finish(user);        
      });
    } else {
      finish(user);
    }
  }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for hinting to this. I'm returning now the user in .save((err, obj) => {return obj}) as an object. However, still can't proceed to the login process afterwards.

Comment: @Ruham - Well, using a callback with `.save()` does not make it easy.  That's why I used promises with `let result = await user.save()` instead.  I made a suggestion for how to do it.  It's your choice if you want to ignore my suggestion, but I showed you one way to do it.

Comment: I tried your version, and it didn't work for some reason (500 server error). I posted the working version but I don't like the code the way it is now.

Comment: @Ruham - Well, I said in my answer that you would have to look at the `result` in `let result = await user.save()` and figure out exactly where your `facebookId` was in the result because I can't look at the data myself.  It looks like in your version, you figure out that you can just set `user.id = result.backbookId` and then it will work so that's what I edited mine too.  You can try that.

Comment: @Ruham - OK, I updated both my version and an improved version of your version in my answer.  I added some error handling in places it was missing too.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the code like this, and it works:

```
/**
 * @route POST api/auth/loginViaFacebook
 * @desc Login User via Facebook/
 * @access public
 */
router.post("/loginViaFacebook", (req, res) => {
  const userEmail = req.body.email;
  const facebookId = req.body.facebookId;

  // Find user by email. ( Down below { email } in ES6 is same as { email: email }
  User.findOne({ email: userEmail }).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      new User({
        facebookId: facebookId,
        name: req.body.name,
        email: userEmail,
        pictureUrl: req.body.picture
      }).save(function(err, user) {
        if (err) res.send({ errors: err });

        const payload = {
          facebookId: user.facebookId,
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          pictureUrl: user.picture
        };

        jwt.sign(payload, secretOrKey, { expiresIn: 3600 }, (err, token) => {
          res.json({ success: true, token: "Bearer " + token });
        });
        return;
      });
    }

    const payload = {
      facebookId: user.facebookId,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      pictureUrl: user.picture
    };

    jwt.sign(payload, secretOrKey, { expiresIn: 3600 }, (err, token) => {
      res.json({ success: true, token: "Bearer " + token });
    });
  });
});
```

I absolutely hate the fact that I had to use the authentication code twice, but it works. Wold appreciate if someone could suggest a refactored version of this code.